# How to make an if clause inside another on MySQL

Tags: mysql, if-statement, triggers

I'm trying to make an trigger that verifies a credit account every time a client makes a purchase to add the invoice total to the amount of the credit that he has accumulated, so i have three tables to match the query:

INVOICE: has the total amount of the new purchase and the vehicle licence number as foreign key.

VEHICLE: has the client id so you can match it with the credit account.

CREDIT_ACCOUNT: has a max credit amount, the acumulated
 credit (it must be <= than the max credit amount to allow the purchase) and the client id as foreing key.

I have troubles trying to find out how an if clause works inside another if clause on MySQL.

this is my trigger code:

```
create trigger Update_Credit_ Account before insert on INVOICE
for each row
begin
if (select exists (select * from INVOICE  join VEHICLE as V on new.LICENSE_PLATE=V.LICENSE_PLATE
join CREDIT_ACCOUNT as CA on V.ID_CLIENT=CA.ID_CLIENT)=true) 
then 
    begin
        if(select (new.TOTAL + CA.ACUMULATED_CREDIT)<= CA.MAX_CREDIT from INVOICE join VEHICLE as V on new.LICENSE_PLATE=V.LICENSE_PLATE join CREDIT_ACCOUNT as CA on V.ID_CLIENT=CA.ID_CLIENT)
        then
            begin 
                update CREDIT_ACCOUNT as CA set ACUMULATED_CREDIT=(new.TOTAL + CA.ACUMULATED_CREDIT) where  CA.ID_CLIENT = V.ID_CLIENT;
            end;
       end if;
end if;
&
```

I'm not used to the syntax of MySQL, so i guess i'm thinking it more like java, could you give me a hand please? thanks in advance.

P.d. I apologize for my bad english skills and hope you can understand me.

Answer (score 0):

The nested if statements are same as the general, you need not begin and end the block for each nested if. Hope this helps...
Sample:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Update_Credit_ Account BEFORE insert ON INVOICE
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (select exists (select * from INVOICE  join VEHICLE as V on new.LICENSE_PLATE=V.LICENSE_PLATE
join CREDIT_ACCOUNT as CA on V.ID_CLIENT=CA.ID_CLIENT)=true) THEN 

        IF(select (new.TOTAL + CA.ACUMULATED_CREDIT)<= CA.MAX_CREDIT from INVOICE join VEHICLE as V on new.LICENSE_PLATE=V.LICENSE_PLATE join CREDIT_ACCOUNT as CA on V.ID_CLIENT=CA.ID_CLIENT) THEN
          UPDATE CREDIT_ACCOUNT as CA set ACUMULATED_CREDIT=(new.TOTAL + CA.ACUMULATED_CREDIT) where  CA.ID_CLIENT = V.ID_CLIENT;
END IF;
END;
```